# Is there a way to use a grouped scale of range of values as legend in a Folium Choropleth Map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, leaflet, folium, choropleth

I am new into creating folium choropleth maps in python and I can't seem to find any helpful resources when it comes to creating a legend with classified data values on it , as opposed to a continous scale colouring. Just to explain what I am trying to do, let's say I have the following Pandas Dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['AR',1,3,2],['NY',3,5,5],['NH',8,0,7],['AL',5,7,9],['AK',9,8,10] ], columns=['states','rate_1','rate_2','rate_3'])
```

with five rows and 4 columns. Now if I was to plot a folium choropleth map of say rate_1 and the states and want the legends to show group values, say, I would like to have 3 ranges of 0-3, 3-6, 6-9, represented by 3 different colours, say, red , blue, and green. So if for the first range of values a red colour  was assigned, I must have 2 states coloured in red 'AR' and 'NY', 1 state coloured in blue 'AL', and 2 states coloured green 'NH' and 'AK'. Below I provide a snippet of the function I am using to create the choropleth map and a screenshot of a map along with it's legend, so as you can have a look at the legend I am trying to create. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
def map_maker(geopandas_dataframe, values_dataframe):
    my_scale = np.linspace(data_df['rate_1'].min(), data_df['rate_1'].max(), 5)
    map = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=4)
    f = folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=geopandas_dataframe,
        name='Map of Rate 1',
        data=values_dataframe,
        columns=['states', 'rate_1'],
        key_on='feature.properties.states',
        fill_color='YlGn',
        fill_opacity=0.2,
        line_opacity=1,
        smooth_factor=0,
        highlight=True,
        threshold_scale=my_scale,
        legend_name=Rates
    ).add_to(map)

    f.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['states', 'rate_1], labels=True))
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)

    return map
```

[An example of the legend that I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgGji.png)